# Is there any way to run PowerShell scripts in Serverspec?

Tags: ruby, powershell, rspec, serverspec, inspec

There are lots of build-in resources in Serverspec, but I want to extend it to my own needs. In InSpec it support script resource which will run the PowerShell script and get the result it seems.

But InSpec is too slow. Is there any equivalent to script resource in Serverspec exists? It is running PowerShell script in the backend for each resource. How to write my own PowerShell script and call it via Serverspec?

Comment: You mean a new resource? You can write your own RSpec matcher for that if you want, but you would also need to write the Windows backend command for it too. If you mean just executing a script, you can do it with the `command` resource. Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am very good at powershell scripting . I can write the backend powershell script. But what i don't know is how to make that available to serverspec. (as i am new to ruby). I want to check sql database table entries, web.config file entries etc. I can write powershell for that. But i want it to be integrated with rspec so that one script to execute all the tests.

Comment: Are you executing your tests remotely or locally?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am executing locally

Comment: Does using a `command` resource to execute the powershell script not work for you?